# how can I implement one-to-many relationships in Django model?

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create one-to-many relationships in Django model. I want to implement it as the bellow image shows.

[image]

here is my code:

```
class Book(models.Model):
   book_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   isbn = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Author(models.Model):
   id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   book_id = models.ForeignKey(Book)//I want to link it with Book.book_id
```

Comment: Hi, `models.ForeignKey` will do that like you have it

Comment: You don't need `book_id` in `Book` and `id` in `Author` as Django automatically assigns an integer primary key (named `id` and additionally aliased `pk`). In `Author`, you may want to rename `book_id` to just `book` since the relationship usually yields a `Book` object in your code even if only the book id is actually stored in the table.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to do that, django automatically assign it for you.

In relational databases, a one-to-many relationship occurs when a parent record in one table can potentially reference several child records in another table. In a one-to-many relationship, the parent is not required to have child records; therefore, the one-to-many relationship allows zero child records, a single child record or multiple child records. To define a many-to-one relationship, use **ForeignKey**

Refer this docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships)